# How do I change an oh-my-zsh bindkey that a plug-in set?

Tags: zsh, command-history, oh-my-zsh, plugin

You can find most of the context on [this github comment](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/issues/544#issuecomment-1499775500). I installed the [zsh-autocomplete plugin](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete) and it adds a feature I don't want: pressing up fills the page with a menu of previous commands I've run. I like the other features but I want the up button to behave like default bash/zsh/oh-my-zsh, cycling through the history one line at a time.

In that first link you can see how to make this change: `bindkey '\e[A' up-line-or-search`. But I don't have enough context to know what to do with that information. I'm not even sure if the answer to my SO question applies to zsh-autocomplete, any plug-in, or zsh/oh-my-zsh as a whole (please let me know in your answer):

Am I supposed to add `bindkey '\e[A' up-line-or-search` to my `~/.zshrc` to overwrite the default, am I supposed to modify something in `~/.oh-my-zsh/lib/key-bindings.zsh`, or am I supposed to change something in another place?

---

UPDATE: The github issue linked to [zsh-autocomplete/.zshrc](https://github.com/marlonrichert/zsh-autocomplete/blob/5cc9da132e7535a540fb1235ce27fd5a233d4f0e/.zshrc#L76). If I looked around more I would've seen the answer to my question at the top of that file:

```bash
# The code below sets all of Autocomplete's settings to their default values. To
# change a setting, copy it into your `.zshrc` file and modify it there.
```

FWIW, you should put this after the file runs `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`. If you put it before, it has no affect.

This answers my main question, but this minor one remains:

> I'm not even sure if the answer to my SO question applies to zsh-autocomplete specifically, any plug-in, or zsh/oh-my-zsh as a whole (please let me know in your answer)